# Summarize the total of a specified item all together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

```
MySQL [distributor]> select * from orderitems;
+-----------+------------+---------+----------+------------+
| order_num | order_item | prod_id | quantity | item_price |
+-----------+------------+---------+----------+------------+
|     20005 |          1 | BR01    |      100 |       5.49 |
|     20005 |          2 | BR03    |      100 |      10.99 |
|     20006 |          1 | BR01    |       20 |       5.99 |
|     20006 |          2 | BR02    |       10 |       8.99 |
|     20006 |          3 | BR03    |       10 |      11.99 |
|     20007 |          1 | BR03    |       50 |      11.49 |
|     20007 |          2 | BNBG01  |      100 |       2.99 |
|     20007 |          3 | BNBG02  |      100 |       2.99 |
|     20007 |          4 | BNBG03  |      100 |       2.99 |
|     20007 |          5 | RGAN01  |       50 |       4.49 |
|     20008 |          1 | RGAN01  |        5 |       4.99 |
|     20008 |          2 | BR03    |        5 |      11.99 |
|     20008 |          3 | BNBG01  |       10 |       3.49 |
|     20008 |          4 | BNBG02  |       10 |       3.49 |
|     20008 |          5 | BNBG03  |       10 |       3.49 |
|     20009 |          1 | BNBG01  |      250 |       2.49 |
|     20009 |          2 | BNBG02  |      250 |       2.49 |
|     20009 |          3 | BNBG03  |      250 |       2.49 |
+-----------+------------+---------+----------+------------+
18 rows in set (0.098 sec)
```

I am able to summarize the total price of a specified order as;

```
MySQL [distributor]> select order_num, sum(quantity*item_price) 
  as total_price from orderitems where order_num = 20008;
+-----------+-------------+
| order_num | total_price |
+-----------+-------------+
|     20008 |      189.60 |
+-----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.026 sec)
```

How could I aggregate the total-price of each order and display them all together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SELECT statement clause that divides the query result into groups of rows, usually for the purpose of performing one or more aggregations on each group. The SELECT statement returns one row per group.

So in your all things are fine  just need group by order_num

```
 select order_num, sum(quantity*item_price) as total_price from orderitems
    group by order_num
```

Answer (score 3):

Use GROUP BY:

```
select order_num, sum(quantity*item_price) as total_price
from orderitems group by order_num
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show total price of all orders which order details, you can remove order num from select:-

```
select sum(quantity*item_price) as total_price from orderitems;
```

However, if you are looking to show total price of all orders against each order, you can use below query :-

```
select order_num, sum(sum(quantity*item_price)) OVER() as total_price 
from orderitems 
group by order_num;
```

Comment: Why are you using `OVER` with `GROUP BY`?  Note that your query would only run on MySQL version 8+ or later.

Comment: OP didn't post any expected output. So I put this code by assuming that he wants to show cumulative value of all orders against each order. Please let me know if any corrections required.